# How to change style of background color using Vue.js only

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'




Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <webpage></webpage>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import webpage from "./components/webpage"


export default {
  name: 'app',
  components : {
    webpage
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

i tried to change the background color of  element with with vue bind styling using the command  `v-bind:style='{backgroundColor : color}`
but its not at full height, even though i tried to remove the margin and the padding for the body element on CSS but still not working as u can see on the pic thanks

```css
#wrapper{
   
    width: 650px  ;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(198, 241, 200);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:rgb(250, 28, 65);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 22):

bind your element to a style object as follows:

```
  <div :style="myStyle" id="wrapper">
```

in your data object :

```
     data(){
       return{
         myStyle:{
            backgroundColor:"#16a085" 
            }
          ...
           }
         }
```

You could check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9652mm90z) i made several changes in your css rules without affecting the Vue logic