# Vue : how to change background color for each page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

i have code below in Vue js below and i wanted to have different background color in each page, but whenever i do that i should go to App.vue and change color from their for all pages cuz the main container here that includes all pages is App , is there a way to change background color for only one page ? thanks in advance

```html
<template>
<b-container>
<h1> Ask Question </h1>
<br>
 <br />
<b-row align-v="center">
<b-col cols="8">

    <b-form-group

  
 @submit="postData" method="post">
      <b-form-input
        type="text"
        name="title"
        v-model="posts.title"
        placeholder="Title"
        required
     
      <b-form-input id="question-input"
        type="text"
        name="question"
        v-model="posts.question"
        placeholder="Question"
        required
      /><br /><br />
    
      <b-button class="primary" type="submit">Post</b-button>
    </b-form-group
>
  
</b-col>

</b-row>



 </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "postComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: {
        title: null,
        question: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    postData(e) {
        this.axios.post("",this.posts).then(( result) => {
console.log(result)
        })
        // console.warn(this.posts)
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&displa');
.container{
    padding:50px;
    font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
}
#question-input{
    padding: 35px 10px 90px;
}


</style>
```

App.vue

```html
<template>


<div class="app">
<Header />
<router-view />
</div>

</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    Header,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};

</script>
<style>
.app{
  width: auto;

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add class and add a background color in the component's scoped style:

```
<template>
  <main class="crypto_bg">
    ...
  </main>
</template>

<style scoped>
 .crypto_bg {
   background: #1d2444;
 }
</style>
```

But for more.
In my case, I have 2 pages: crypto, and stock, controlled by a toggler in the Header.vue.
The stock page is like the home/default page, my unique page with a different background for header and body is the crypto page.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header @stock="showStockPlatform" @crypto="showCryptoPlatform" />

    <Main v-if="stockMainShown" />

    <CryptoMain v-if="cryptoMainShown" />

    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
        stockMainShown: true,
        cryptoMainShown: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showStockPlatform: function (platform) {
        this.stockMainShown = platform;
    },

    showCryptoPlatform: function (platform) {
        this.cryptoMainShown = platform;
    },
  },
</script>
```

In my Header.vue where I'm toggling to show this unique page/component:

Emit an event from your Header.vue to update the App.vue, setting a variable for this unique page to be true e.g stockMainShown: true, cryptoMainShown: false, as seen above.

```
<script>
 export default {
  data() {
    return {
        stockPlat: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showPlatform(platform) {
        if (platform.toLowerCase() == "stocks") {

            this.$emit("stock", true);
            this.$emit("crypto", false);

            this.stockPlat = true;
        } else if (platform.toLowerCase() == "crypto") {

            this.$emit("stock", false);
            this.$emit("crypto", true);

            this.stockPlat = !this.stockPlat;
        }
    },
  },
 };
</script>
```

Inside the Template tag, change the header background color if it's this unique page, i.e where stockPlat is false as seen below

```
<template>
  <div :class="[stockPlat ? 'bgDark' : 'bgBlue']">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Inside the Style tag, use this

```
<style>
  .bgDark {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .bgBlue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Reference:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.style.backgroundColor = "<your color here>";`

You should have access to `document` from within any of your methods in your vue object, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can add:

```css
.backgroundcolor {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

to your CSS, and all you will have to do is change `lightblue` to the color you want the background to be and add `class="backgroundcolor"` to the first tag, for example; the `<body>` tag would work or something similar to the `<body>` tag also the `<html>` tag can work for this as well, but I normally you wouldn't have a `class=""` in the `<html>` tag.

Also, go here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp
for info on pretty much everything to do with coding, but I can say that https://www.w3schools.com is more of a place to go for tutorials on the basics of coding in many different coding languages.

Take a look at these: https://codepen.io/alemesa/pen/YNrBqr and [How to change style of background color using Vue.js only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229804/how-to-change-style-of-background-color-using-vue-js-only) one of them could work.

Comment: well, this can work with normal HTML,CSS project but with Vue Js no cuz as i explained the parent div is an App.vue so when i change color of any other page it didn't apply for the whole page width

Comment: @sara97 take a look at these: https://codepen.io/alemesa/pen/YNrBqr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229804/how-to-change-style-of-background-color-using-vue-js-only one of them could work.